# DateOffset with pandas timestamp giving an error

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have created a DataFrame with a datetime and a column indicating number of minutes this represents since an 'epoch' I have defined as 1st Jan 1900 00:00.  I am only interested in minute level accuracy here.

```
    from pandas.tseries.offsets import *

    df = pd.DataFrame([pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000'),
              pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01 00:01:00.000000'),
              pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01 00:02:00.000000'),],
              columns=['datetimeinput'])
```

This works OK, with the function

```
    def MinsSince1900(dt):
        epoch = pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000')
        elapsedmins = (dt - epoch).astype('timedelta64[m]')
        return elapsedmins
```

and I can get the column timekey back as 0, 1, 2 minutes since the epoch, with:

```
    df.loc[:,'timekey']= MinsSince1900(df['datetimeinput'])
```

However, when I try to reverse this process and convert the timekey back to a time, with the following function:

```
    def CreateTimefromKey(t):
        x=pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000') + DateOffset(minutes=t)
        y = x.to_datetime()
        return y
```

I get an error message

```
    TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta minutes component: Series
```

I am clearly doing something wrong here with offset, timestamp and series.  But I thought if it worked one way, I could reverse the process.

If somebody could point out where I am going wrong I would be very grateful, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Series of `timedelta64[ns]`s to the `epoch` (Pandas Timestamp):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000'),
          pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01 00:01:00.000000'),
          pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01 00:02:00.000000'),],
          columns=['datetimeinput'])
epoch = pd.Timestamp('1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000')
df['timekey'] = (df['datetimeinput'] - epoch) / pd.Timedelta(minutes=1)
df['date'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['timekey'], unit='m') + epoch
```

yields

```
        datetimeinput  timekey                date
0 1900-01-01 00:00:00        0 1900-01-01 00:00:00
1 1900-01-01 00:01:00        1 1900-01-01 00:01:00
2 1900-01-01 00:02:00        2 1900-01-01 00:02:00
```